# How restore point works in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup

I am trying to create a backup for my C Drive having windows 10 ( C drive was crashed last time and I've lost a lot of data; error was 'boot file missing' ).

I have installed games, softwares etc in my C Drive, now I am confused how to back up the data. And one option is restore point but please elaborate it, how it work and how I will get my data back via restore point if something happened to drive C.

Comment: welcome to superuser. You can find a lot of information on the internet on how to back-up your data and also how to manage restore points (Those are two different things!!). Your current question is too broad now as it's not possible to give you a good answer within reasonable size, please have a look on help center and reword your question.

Comment: System Restore does not back up your data, it just preserves a system state, which preserves the OS in case changes you make go wrong. Best thing to do is create a Recovery Drive every so often as you add files and games, you need to make a new recovery drive...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/create-a-recovery-drive

Comment: @Moab +1 for your explanation.You mean i should keep my one extra USB drive for my c drive backup right ? Moreover if system restore preserves a system state how can i preserver my current system state and then how i can get it back if something wrong happens to my C Drive.

Comment: System state is completely different than a backup, yes you need to make a recovery drive and update it occasionally. System restore is good for situations like you install a driver or software that messes up windows proper operation, system restore reverts all the changes the driver or software made.

Answer (score 0):

The `'boot file missing'` error does not neccessarily mean that you lost your data. As a possible solution you might need to repair the boot sector of your operating system, for example as is described here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows. But if you provide more details how did you lost your data than another solution could be found but anyway it is not possible to restore a data like programs, games etc. from a restore point if the drive was formatted. Only config data iis stored at a restore point.